# Why can't my Javascript access Twitter when running on a local server?

Tags: javascript, linux, twitter, webserver

I created an html page that uses Javascript based off of the code found [here](http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/).

It works correctly when the html is loaded directly into the browser as a file. However I'm trying to use it in conjunction with a Chrome plugin that doesn't work on websites accessed as a file.

To solve this problem, I set up a simple webserver with the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`but when the webpage is accessed this way it doesn't seem to be able to access information from Twitter.

Why is that?

If I could give permission to the plugin to work on files, this would also work as an alternate solution so that I do not have to use the webserver method. I do not know how to do this though.

Either solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file you need to allow access to the domain where the data is located, so if your trying to access `api.twitter.com` you manifest.json file would look a little like so:

```
{
    "name"      : "Your Application",
    ...
    "permissions"       : [
        "https://api.twitter.com/*",
        "tabs",
    ]
    ....
}
```

Also in Manage Extension in Google Chrome you you can enable developer mode and inspect your background.html page to find errors in the console.